# Prove $A^TB$ is a positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

$A,B \in R^{m\times n}$ and the singular values of both $A$ and $B$ are between 0 and 1. Is $A^TB$ a positive semi-definite matrix? Please show me the proof:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not.  You can always rescale $A$ and $B$ so their singular values are between $0$ and $1$, but that doesn't affect positive semidefiniteness of $A^T B$.

Comment: But the singular values are all non-negative, I guess $A^TB$ should be positive semi-definite and I cannot find a counter example.

Comment: The singular values are irrelevant. It is the eigenvalues that matter. Or rather, the eigenvalues of $A^TB+B^TA$.

Answer (score 2):

Try 
$$A=1, \qquad B=-1$$
$1\times 1$ matrices

Comment: The singular value of B is not between 0 and 1.

Comment: the singular value of $B$ is 1

Comment: I would think it is -1?

Comment: singular value $\ne$ eigenvalues. They are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $B^tB$, and they're always positive